# How can I get global $post to work for CPT and update user?

Tags: posts, user-meta, count, views

Ive created a custom field in my user_meta which now I want to update the count each time one the user posts are viewed.

Ive got this which works great for standard wordpress posts. However I need it to count for two post types, Receipes and Menus.

Can anyone help please

```
 add_filter('the_content','update_user_count');
    function update_user_count($content){
        global $post;
        $counter = 0;
        $score = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'views', true );
        $counter += $score;
        update_user_meta( $post->post_author, 'wpcf-count', $counter);
        return $content;
    }
```

Comment: having a DB write on each page view is a great way to bring a site down, and will not work if there is page caching applied

Comment: Is there a way to do this and put it on the single post template?

Comment: why does it matter? you should not write to the DB on a front end request, or at least try to avoid it as much as possible

Comment: How else would you go about getting this to happen?

Comment: use google analytics, and use their API to retrieve data, or write to a file and process it daily

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why are you hooking into `the_content` filter. You could use a more appropriate action hook, such as `wp_head`:

```
<?php
add_action ( 'wp_head', 'update_user_count' ); // note
function update_user_count()
{
    global $post;

    // Make sure you only get the int part
    $counter = ( int ) get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'views', true );

    // increment counter by 1
    // http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php
    $counter++;

    update_user_meta( $post->post_author, 'wpcf-count', $counter);
}
```

This should work as intended now, I have a similar piece of code to update my blog's views count. But notice, `global $post` only works properly in the loop. You should add some checks to see if you are in a loop, or if the `$post` variable is actually set.

Comment: Hi Thanks, This nearly works.. However it does not add. It simply copys the views across. So for example if I had 3 posts. Post A, Post B and Post C. If Post A has 3 views on it will update the count field in the users meta to 3, but then If I am viewing Post C which only have 1 view on it, it will then update the count field to 1. Where as it should add 3+1

Comment: That's because this is your nonworking code. The only thing was modified is the action hook.

Comment: See edited code.

Comment: Are able to help on how I can achieve so it adds and then updates the vies into the counter field please